# Why is the CSS attribute Backface-Visibility: hidden not displaying the front face when the card is flipped?

Tags: html, css

When the card is flipped, the front face is turned to the back and hidden, however, the back face is turned but not made visible. My intention is to have whichever side of the card is front-facing made visible. I have tried a number of variations of placing the backface-visibility attribute within different classes/ids but to no avail.

Below is my current code:

```css
body {  
    background-image: url("imgs/Bike-Logo.jpg");  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-position: top left;  
    background-attachment: fixed;  
    background-size: 100% 100%;  
}

.container {  
  background: inherit;  
}

.card {  
  width: 350px;  
  height: 500px;  
  background: inherit;  
  position: absolute;  
  overflow: hidden;  
  top: 50%;  
  left: 50%;  
  margin-left: -175px;  
  margin-top: -250px;  
  border-radius: 8px;  
  background-color: #707075;  
  transition: transform 0.8s;  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  
}

.card::before {  
  content: "";  
  position: absolute;  
  top: -25px;  
  left: -25px;  
  bottom: 0;  
  right: 0;  
  /*frosted div effect*/  
  background: inherit;    
  box-shadow: 100px 0px 20px 200px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);   
  filter: blur(20px);  
}

.flip_card_back {  
  transform: rotateY(180deg);  
}

.card.flipped {  
  transform: rotateY(180deg);  
}

.flip_card_front, .flip_card_back {  
  backface-visibility: hidden;  
}

.sign_up_form {  
  position: relative;  
  margin: 10%;  
  background-color: red;  

}
.sign_in_form {  
    position: relative;    
    margin: 10%;    
  background-color: blue;    
}

.card figure {  
    color: white;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="card"> 

            <div class="flip_card_front">
                <form>
                    <div class="sign_in_form">

                        <figure>Front</figure>

                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>


            <div class="flip_card_back">
                <form >
                    <div class="sign_up_form" > 

                        <figure>Back</figure>

                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>


    <button  id="flip">Sign In -></button>  
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest reading this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp

Comment: @EvertvdH. Have I missed understood the explanation from W3Schools? Why would the attribute still hide the div class="flip_card_back" once it is front facing?

Comment: Can you update your snippet so it reproduces your issue? right now I can see the content when it's front facing.

Comment: @EvertvdH. This is my latest snippet that reproduces my issue. I'm using Chrome so it cannot be a browser issue. Are you able to view the figure with the text "Back"?

Comment: @EvertvdH. I found that the "overflow" attribute in #card is overriding the backface-visibility.  Because the content is not overflowing the element box, the overflow attribute forces it to be visible despite it being back facing. I assume this is because of the parent-child relationship.